# In Python 3, using Pytest, how do we test for exit code : exit(1) and exit(0) for a python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, pytest, exit-code

I am new to Pytest in python .

I am facing a tricky scenario where I need to test for exit codes - exit(1) and exit(0) , using Pytest module.
Below is the python program :

```
 def sample_script():
     count_file  = 0
     if count_file == 0:
        print("The count of files is zero")
     exit(1)
     else:
         print("File are present")
     exit(0)
```

Now I want to test the above program for exit codes, exit(1) and exit(0) . Using Pytest how we can frame the test code so that we can test or asset the exit code of the function sample_script ?

Please help me.

Comment: @ Martin Prikryl , can you help me on this ?

Comment: Why not replace the `exit()` with an `assert()` or `raise()`?

Comment: @Martin Prikryl , can you help me on this ?

Comment: @Jens , we need to test for exit code only . The function sample_script () 
is having exit code ,  exit(1) and exit(0) . Using Pytest , we need to have a test program which tests for the exit code of sample_script ()

Comment: You Python function doesn't make sense, it will always exit with code 1, the else branch will never be reached.

Comment: @pavelsaman , yes , it always exits with code 1.  But how we can test it in using Pytest ? I need to test for exit code 1 using Pytest program. I need help in framing a Pytest program for it.

Comment: you could use a subprocess and check the exit code. not very pretty, but it would work.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to test something that every reasonable IDE will mark as error even before executing your code. If you want to ignore all these errors gathered during the statis analysis, it's a sure path to problems later on.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Once you put the `exit(1)` inside the if block as suggested, you can test for [SystemExit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit) exception:

```py
from some_package import sample_script


def test_exit():
    with pytest.raises(SystemExit) as pytest_wrapped_e:
        sample_script()
    assert pytest_wrapped_e.type == SystemExit
    assert pytest_wrapped_e.value.code == 42
```

The example is taken from here: https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/testing-sys-exit-with-pytest-10c6e5f7726f

UPDATE:

Here's a complete working example you can copy/paste to test:

```py
import pytest

def sample_func():
    exit(1)

def test_exit():
    with pytest.raises(SystemExit) as e:
        sample_func()
    assert e.type == SystemExit
    assert e.value.code == 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_exit()
```

Comment: in the exmaple code shared by you , where I can call or place my python function, sample_script()  , so that I can test for exit code 1 ?

Comment: I tried as you suggested , but facing the below error :

AttributeError : 'ExceptionInfo' object has no attribute 'type'

Comment: Give me a second to try it

Comment: Everything works, please double check how you run it.

Comment: I am trying to run it in PyCharm console. Trying to execute the Pytest program using the command py.test -v -s  in  terminal window . It is  failing  by the error :  AttributeError : 'ExceptionInfo' object has no attribute 'type'  ..

How are trying to execute the Pytest program ?

Comment: thank you so much . Its working fine now. Got successful .